# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar fragmentos de código (snippets)?

Tags: soporte, stack-snippets

> ¡Sigue siendo un misterio a la hora de elaborar preguntas en **Stack Overflow**!

Al formular una pregunta tenemos a la derecha este símbolo ❔ de ayuda.

En ayuda avanzada de [español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) es muy diferente a la ayuda avanzada en [ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

No lo menciono por el idioma si no por las diferentes opciones de código que serían muy útiles que también se encuentren en español al igual que todos los códigos ocultos que no están presente en la ayuda avanzada.

> Ahora mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar un fragmento en **StackOverflow**?

No recuerdo muy bien en qué pregunta vi este nombre tipo enlace *Mostrar fragmento*. Al hacer clic en *(Mostrar fragmento)* mostraba de cada ejemplo un código extenso.

Sería muy útil saber para elaborar preguntas que conste en varios ejemplos. ¿Qué código se emplea para realizar aquella función?

Comment: Un pequeño detalle: en la ayuda avanzada de español, estás haciendo referencia a la ayuda de meta. La ayuda del sitio está en **[Ayuda de markdown](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)**. Esta **es igual** a la de SO (sólo difieren en las tablas que se agregaron para Documentation, que obviamente no están disponibles).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El gran problema que enfrentan los usuarios nuevos al iniciarse en *Stack Overflow* es el uso extendido de [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) que puede ser un poco traumático al principio. De eso es lo que tratan las [páginas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) a las que haces referencia, una guía de las reglas de *markdown* que se pueden utilizar en el sitio con *algunas extensiones* propias.

Yo en lo personal agradezco a *Stack Overflow* por esto, ya que su uso está muy extendido en lugares como [GitHub](https://github.com/), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) y otros sitios que frecuentan los programadores.

Si quieres aprender un poco mejor las conversiones que hacen estas reglas puedes consultar la documentación oficial y probar la herramienta online [Dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus).

Debes tener en cuenta que no es lo mismo un bloque de código [image: bloque de codigo] que un *snippet* de código [image: snippet].

El primero te permitirá **resaltar** código de cualquier lenguaje:

```css
<!-- language: lang-java -->
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

... mientras que el segundo te permitirá **resaltar y ejecutar** código en `CSS, HTML y Javascript`:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var foo = console.log('bar');

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .foo {
      width: 10em;
      background-color: #d0e0f0;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="foo">foo</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Los *snippets*, son los únicos que se pueden colapsar. Es posible que debas hacer scroll de acuerdo al tamaño de tu pantalla. Para ocultarlo hay una opción en la parte *inferior-izquierda*.

[image: Ocultar sippet]

> Nota: Aunque dice *"Ocultar de forma predeterminada"*, no es de manera predeterminada. Esto es porque al agregar *un segundo snippet*, deja de estar oculto, lo cual no se mantiene en el tiempo.

El *snippet ocultado* se verá así:

```js
var foo = console.log('bar');
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #d0e0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

Esto es muy útil para acortar el tamaño de la pregunta y respuesta cuando tienes muchos fragmentos de código.

También puedes cambiarlo directamente en el texto con la opción `hide`, pasando de `false` a `true`. El texto inicial de los *snippets* es parecido al siguiente:

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Cambia `hide` a `true` y tendrás el mismo resultado:

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true  console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Muy completa. Cabe aclarar que la opción de *ocultar de forma predeterminada* es sólo Stack Snippets (para JavaScript/HTML/CSS), y que no se puede ocultar código de otros lenguajes.

Comment: @Mariano Si. Aunque intentes trucar el resaltado del código cambiando el lenguaje manualmente por ejemplo a `language: lang-java`  se desabilita el snippet por completo. Respuesta editada :)