# Uso de fragmentos o bloques de código ejecutable (code snippet) cuando respondemos en SO

Tags: discusión, stack-snippets

La ayuda de Stackoverflow dice que podemos usar fragmentos de código que se pueden ejecutar en nuestra respuesta misma.

Es una función bastante útil.

Ejemplo de fragmento que combina JavaScript, CSS y HTML:

```html
<!-- begin snippet: ... -->

    Contenido precedido del lenguaje al que pertenece...

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    Contenido JavaScript...

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    Contenido CSS...

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    Contenido HTML...

     Y al final...

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Cuando está bien construido se puede ver debajo el botón `Ejecutar` desde el cual se puede probar el código.

Por ejemplo:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
            'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'
        ],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'
        ],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Mi&eacute;rcoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'S&aacute;bado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mi&eacute;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'S&aacute;b'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'S&aacute;'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        appendText: ' Haga click para introducir una fecha'
    });
});
```

```css
div,label,input{
  background-color: #d0e0f090;
}
```

```html
<!-- Librerías -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <label>Ingrese Fecha:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fecha" readonly id="datepicker1">
</div>
```

Ahora viene mi pregunta:

La [ayuda de SO en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) da ejemplos para JavaScript, HTML, C#... Pero, ¿Se puede usar esta técnica para otros lenguajes tales como Java, PHP, SQL? ¿Cómo se combina JavaScript con HTML? ¿Se podría combinar por ejemplo PHP y HTML en un bloque de código y verlo correr en nuestras respuestas? ¿Existe un catálogo de sintaxis para los lenguajes más usados al que uno pueda referirse?

Comment: No. Sólo hay Snippets para JavaScript/HTML/CSS. Para el resto, se usa el botón `{  }` para darle formato, pero no es ejecutable. Desde luego, podrías incluir un enlace a la demo en otra página.

Comment: Probablemente encuentres toda esta información en [Códigos ocultos en stackoverflow - ¿Cómo Mostrar y ocultar fragmento?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/907/127)

Comment: Gracias @Mariano. No pensé en lo del demo porque inicialmente la pregunta estaba en SO, no en meta porque consideraba que era más útil allí, pero fue migrada. Allí corría el código en la misma pregunta.

Comment: Con lo de demo, me refería a publicar el código en páginas como http://ideone.com/, http://rextester.com/, etc. y agregar el enlace a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano porque la idea del fragmento de código que adjunté era para que se viera cómo funcionaban los snippets en las respuestas-preguntas de SO, y no probar que el código en sí funcionaba Una vez trasladado a la sección meta la presencia del código completo pierde su sentido, así que estoy considerando eliminar esa parte de la pregunta.

Comment: No hace falta. Todos sabemos cómo funciona y qué estás queriendo decir.

Comment: Yo recomiendo dejar esa parte. Hay muchos usuarios que creen que eso funciona para todo tipo de código, así como hay usuarios que no saben de la existencia de esta funcionalidad. El ejemplo ayuda a reforzar ambas ideas.

Comment: @A.Cedano para MS SQL/MySQL/SQLite se puede usar [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), sin embargo, su funcionalidad es limitada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que la pregunta abarca dos características de SOes:

1. Resaltador de sintáxsis para código.
2. Complemento de fragmentos de código ejecutable.

Ambos conceptos hacen uso de markdown, de hecho, se podría decir que el segundo depende del primero.

En la documentación en inglés:

- Al primero [se le llama](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **"Syntax highlighting for code"**.
- Al segundo [se le llama](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) **"Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets"**, o simplemente **"Stack Snippet"**.

Cabe hacer notar que:

1. La sección de la página de la ayuda a la que se hace referencia en la pregunta se refiere al *resaltado de sintaxis para código* pero no abarca los detalles del *complemento de fragmentos de código ejecutable*.
2. El complemento de fragmento de código ejecutable sólo admite JavaScript, CSS y HTML.

   - Referencia (ya mostrada): [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Una pista de la limitación de los lenguajes soportados por el complmento está en el texto que muestra la interfaz al pasar el puntero sobre el botón para insertar un fragmento de código es `fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS` seguido de la combinación de teclas para insertarlo  <kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd></kbd> .

[image]

> Nota: Aunque se puede ver en la captura de pantalla que CSS está luego de HTML, al momento de insertar el snippet, el orden en *el código fuente* siempre es el mismo, JavaScript, CSS y HTML. El *código fuente* se refiere al momento de editar la publicación.
>
> Esto significa incluso que si se cambia el orden manualmente, y luego se lo vuelve a editar, presionando el enlace **editar este fragmento de código**, y luego se lo guarda presionando el botón **Guardar e insertar**, se reestablece el orden de los lenguajes para tal snippet.

No he encontrado una página en la ayuda sobre este complemento, me parece que sólo existe la documentación creada por la comunidad.

Por ejemplo estas dos:

- Publicación sobre la opción de ocultar código: [¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar fragmentos de código (snippets)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/907)
- Otra publicación reciente aquí en [meta]: [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463)

Comment: Gracias. ¿Esto no aplica entonces a SO? ¿O sí aplica al menos para la sintaxis? Al final: Hinting: Language Codes : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109

Comment: @A.Cedano: Recién otro miembro del sitio hizo la traducción y la publicó como wiki de la comunidad: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463/qu%C3%A9-es-el-resaltado-de-sintaxis-c%C3%B3mo-funciona

Comment: Me parece que en la pregunta se mezclan los conceptos de "resaltado de código" con el de "complemento de fragmento de código ejecutable". En un momento actualizaré mi respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano: He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la información.

Comment: Continué navegado sobre el tema y llegué a la wiki de la etiqueta stack-snippet en [so]. --> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info y esta a su vez a esta pregunta en [meta.so] -> [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1595451)