# ¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?

Tags: soporte, faq, resaltado-de-sintaxis

> Esta es una traducción de [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/209901).

Veo que a veces mi código aparece resaltado en colores diferentes cuando se representa.

- ¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis?
- ¿Cómo funciona?
- ¿Por qué mi código no está resaltado correctamente?
- ¿Cómo informo de un bug o solicito un nuevo lenguaje?
- ¿Cómo se determina el lenguaje para el resaltador de sintaxis?
- ¿Qué lenguajes hay habilitados actualmente en Stack Exchange?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción a la respuesta aceptada en [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/209901). Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

## ¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis?

El resaltado de sintaxis permite que el código presente en las publicaciones, se muestre resaltado de acuerdo con el lenguaje en el que está escrito, de modo que sea más fácil de leer.

## ¿Cómo funciona?

**Stack Exchange no tiene su propio motor de resaltado de sintaxis.** Usa [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Por lo tanto, cualquier bug (issue o problema) o solicitudes de funcionalidad sobre el resaltado de sintaxis no pueden ser gestionados por Stack Exchange y deberían dirigirse al equipo que gestiona Google Code Prettify.

El resaltado de sintaxis, se aplica a la previsualización de la publicación que estás creando o editando. Esto ocurre en cuanto dejas de escribir durante 5 segundos.

[Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) tiene una lista de [core languages](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.js) en los que puede aplicar el resaltado. Esta lista incluye JavaScript/CoffeScript, CSS, HTML, RegEx, XML, C/C++, C#, Java, Perl, Python, Ruby, Bash, así como un genérico resaltado *por defecto* que funciona pasablemente en la mayoría de los lenguajes de tipo C y lenguajes de marcado del tipo HTML. Otros lenguajes adicionales, se implementan como [extensiones](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src) (cada fichero `lang-*.js`).

## ¿Por qué mi código no está resaltado correctamente?

Si tu publicación, no tiene el resaltado correcto, probablemente es porque no está admitido. Echale una ojeada a la [lista de lenguajes admitidos por Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#user-content-for-which-languages-does-it-work). Si tu lenguaje no está en la lista, es necesario que sea creado en el proyecto Prettify antes de ser implementado por parte de Stack Exchange.

Si un lenguaje que debería ser aplicado a una etiqueta ya está en la lista pero no lo usa Stack Exchange, por favor abre una solicitud de característica nueva en Meta para que se asocie el lenguaje en esa etiqueta.

## ¿Cómo informo de un bug o solicito un nuevo lenguaje?

Si es realmente un bug en el resaltados de sintaxis, mira la [lista de problemas](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) para ver si ya ha sido notificado. Si no aparece allí, notifícalo o [únete al proyecto](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/graphs/contributors) y envía la solución tú mismo. Si quieres asegurarte de que el tema que notificas, se resuelva rápidamente, es mejor que incluyas la solución en el mismo informe. Si la solución ya ha sido implementada por parte de Prettify pero no funciona aquí, por favor abre una petición de característica aquí en Meta para que se despliegue una nueva versión de Prettify.

También puedes enviar una petición para que un nuevo lenguaje sea añadido en la [misma lista de problemas](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues). Ten en cuenta que Stack Exchange *no* mantiene este resaltador de sintaxis, así que publicar peticiones de característica o reportes de errores aquí en Meta no hará que se implementen o solucionen.

Antes de que hagas nada, asegúrate de que tienes el resaltado correcto activado.

## ¿Cómo se determina el lenguaje para el resaltador de sintaxis?

Stack Exchange usa [las etiquetas de la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) para inferir el lenguaje que estás usando. Si hay más de una etiqueta que tiene resaltador de sintaxis, usa uno por defecto y deja que Prettify infiera cuál es el mejor lenguaje a usar.

Si tienes curiosidad por saber si una etiqueta tiene una pista de lenguaje, cualquier usuario puede verificarlo mirando la página wiki de la etiqueta. Si hay pista de lenguaje actualmente en uso para esa etiqueta, se mostrará al final de la página, debajo de los botones de la wiki:

> [image: Lenguaje de código (utilizado para resaltar la sintaxis): lang-java]

Es posible [sobreescribir explícitamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) el resaltado en uso con el lenguaje que elijas. Puedes hacerlo indicando la pista de lenguaje como un comentario HTML, justo encima del fragmento de código:

```css
<!-- language: lang-o-una-etiqueta -->

    el código va aquí
```

También puedes usar un *código de lenguaje* o un nombre de *etiqueta* en la pista de lenguaje para activar el resaltado de sintaxis. Más abajo tienes una lista completa de los códigos de lenguajes de *prettify* permitidos.

Por ejemplo:

```javascript
'Este es un bloque de código con un código de lenguaje como pista: '

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function greet(person) {
        return "Hello " + person;
    }
    var user = "John Doe";
    alert(greet(user));

'Este es un bloque de código con un nombre de etiqueta como pista: '

<!-- language: typescript -->

    var arr = [0, 1, 2];
```

Si no quieres que haya ningún tipo de resaltado de sintaxis, usa el lenguaje `lang-none`:

```css
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

También puedes aplicar la pista de lenguaje a *todos* los bloques de código en tu publicación (para no tener que añadir una pista antes de cada uno de ellos):

```css
<!-- language-all: lang-o-una-etiqueta -->
```

Puedes especificar cualquier etiqueta que exista en el sitio, y usará el código que esté actualmente asociado con esa etiqueta (que puede ser *null* (sin pista), *default* o un código de lenguaje *específico*).

---

## Pistas: Códigos de lenguaje

Esta es la lista completa de cada identificador que puedes usar en la pista de lenguaje para el resaltado de sintaxis.

Están agrupadas y actualizadas en [Un poco más de color para SOes (en el código)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1841/83).

```
      Lenguaje        Etiqueta                     Relacionadas                  
 ------------------ ------------- ---------------------------------------------- 
  Sin resaltado      lang-none                                                   
  Por omisión        default                                                     
  Angular            lang-js                                                 
  Bash / Shell       lang-bash     lang-bsh, lang-csh, lang-sh                   
  C                  lang-c        lang-cc                                       
  C#                 lang-cs                                                     
  C++                lang-cpp      lang-cxx, lang-cyc, lang-m                   
  Clojure            lang-clj                                                    
  CoffeeScript       lang-coffee                                                 
  CSH                lang-csh      lang-bsh, lang-csh, lang-sh                   
  CSS                lang-css                                                    
  Dart               lang-dart                                                   
  Delphi             lang-pascal                                                 
  Erlang             lang-erl      lang-erlang                                   
  F#                 lang-fs       lang-ml                                       
  FreePascal         lang-pascal                                                 
  Go                 lang-go                                                     
  Haskell            lang-hs                                                     
  HTML               lang-html     lang-xml, lang-xsl
```

```
      Lenguaje        Etiqueta                     Relacionadas                  
 ------------------ ------------- ----------------------------------------------
  Java               lang-java                                                   
  JavaScript         lang-js       lang-javascript                               
  JSON               lang-json                                                   
  LaTeX              lang-latex    lang-tex                                      
  Lisp               lang-lisp     lang-cllang-el, lang-lsp, lang-scm, lang-rkt  
  LotusScript        lang-vb                                                     
  Lua                lang-lua                                                    
  MATLAB             lang-matlab                                                 
  Maven              lang-xml                                                    
  MySQL              lang-sql                                                    
  Ocaml              lang-ml                                                     
  Pascal             lang-pascal                                                 
  Perl               lang-pl       lang-perl                                     
  PHP                lang-php                                                    
  PostgreSQL         lang-sql                                                    
  Protocol Buffers   lang-proto                                                  
  Python             lang-py       lang-python, lang-cv                          
  R                  lang-r        lang-s                                        
  RegEx              lang-regex
```

```
      Lenguaje        Etiqueta                     Relacionadas                  
 ------------------ ------------- ----------------------------------------------
  Ruby               lang-rb       lang-ruby                                     
  Rust               lang-rust     lang-rc, lang-rs                              
  S                  lang-s                                                      
  Scala              lang-scala                                                  
  Scheme             lang-scm                                                    
  SML                lang-ml                                                     
  SQL                lang-sql                                                    
  Swift              lang-swift
  TeX                lang-tex                                                    
  Turbo-Pascal       lang-pascal                                                 
  TypeScript         lang-js       lang-javascript                               
  VBScript           lang-vbs                                                    
  VHDL               lang-vhdl     lang-vhd                                      
  Visual Basic       lang-vb       lang-vbs                                      
  XML                lang-xml      lang-xsl                                      
  XSL                lang-xsl
```

## Pistas: Etiquetas

Si especificas una etiqueta que existe en el sitio, se utilizará el código de lenguaje que esté asociado con esa etiqueta (que puede ser o bien *null* (sin pista), *default* o un código de lenguaje *específico*).

Ten en cuenta que todas las etiquetas empiezan con código de lenguaje `none`. Las etiquetas cuyo código de lenguaje se defina como `none` se ignorarán y revertirán a `default`.

También puedes usar la palabra `none` tal cual para especficiar manualmente que no quieres que se realice resaltado de sintaxis, que tiene el mismo efecto que el `lang-none` que se indicó más arriba.

---

> #### Nota para los editores:
>
> **Por favor no añadas nada a la lista de arriba a menos que estés %100 seguro de que existe**. Solo porque escribas algo y *parezca* resaltado *no queire decir* que realmente exista en el sistema. Ten en cuenta que los identificadores inválidos, se convierten a *default*. **Por favor, enlaza a la pregunta Meta que confirma la existencia de la pista de lenguaje en el resumen de tu edición**, cuando añadas alguna pista a la lista.
>
> #### Nota para los comentaristas:
>
> Los comentarios en esta FAQ son para consultar sobre algo que no esté claro de esta publicación, de modo de poder aclarar la redacción. Por favor, **no** preguntes, si un lengaje determinado se puede incorporar. Esa no es una pregunta que podamos responder, dado que Stack Exchage no mantiene a este resaltador. Visita [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) para ver el soporte de un lenguaje.