# ¿Cómo puedo insertar código de Python en una pregunta?

Tags: discusión, formato

Quiero hacer una pregunta insertando mi código como guía, pero no encuentro la opción de insertar código de Python.

Comment: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: @abulafia y ¿por qué no volver tu aporte en wiki de comunidad?, considero que sería de altísima utilidad para el resto de la comunidad

Comment: @abulafia Mira esto: [GitHub Oneboxes (Meta SOen)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394055)...  Cuando implementen eso aquí en SOes, simplemente poner el enlace se mostraría... No creo que funcione con _bit.ly_, ya que esos acortadores los consideraría spam. [Dejo el enlace directo a tu Gist](https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/b9a02ac828091125bf8062dd0203a55d). Por cierto, ya te hice follow en GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar código (formato markdown) tienes que pulsar <kbd>`</kbd> 3 veces (es la tecla que está justo a la derecha de la <kbd>P</kbd>).

Luego pones el código y luego cierras con otras 3 <kbd>`</kbd>.

El sistema debería reconocer el lenguaje automáticamente.

Ejemplo de código Python:

````py
```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,socket
print 'Antinmap detecta y bannea(bloquea) ips que intentan escanear este servidor.'
filtro_pcap  = '"inbound and dst portrange 1-32000 "'
nips         = 256
```
````

Que se ve así:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,socket
print 'Antinmap detecta y bannea(bloquea) ips que intentan escanear este servidor.'
filtro_pcap  = '"inbound and dst portrange 1-32000 "'
nips         = 256
```

Comment: de hecho aunque es válido como lo mencionas, el sistema pone a nuestra disposición para formatear código, un ícono con esta figura: `{}` donde primero seleccionamos el fragmento de código y luego lo presionamos o podemos igualmente seleccionar el código y presionar `ctrl + k`

Comment: Lo de _El sistema debería reconocer el lenguaje automáticamente_ tiene que ver con [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83) y no es exactamente automático sino que tiene algunas casuísticas. Para asegurar que reconoce el lenguaje puedes usar `<!-- language: lang-python -->`.