# Error en formato de código por salto de línea en cadenas o mezcla de comillas dobles y simples

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño, resaltado-de-sintaxis

Respondiendo una pregunta, veo que el código que coloqué no aparece correctamente:

Esto no aparece correctamente, se pierde el formato por "romper" la cadena con el salto de línea o por usar comillas simples dentro de una cadena delimitada por comillas dobles (¿o viceversa?).

```
$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa (numero, cliente, fecha, forma_pago)
    VALUES ('$numero', '$cliente', '$fecha', '$forma_pago')";
```

Para que se vea bien, hay que colocar todo en una sola línea:

```
$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa (numero, cliente, fecha, forma_pago) VALUES ('$numero', '$cliente', '$fecha', '$forma_pago')";
```

El problema es que en una sola línea, se agrega barra de desplazamiento horizontal y complica la lectura del código. Lamentablemente aquí no se ve el efecto, pero agrego imagen para mostrar el resultado:

[image: En imagen]

Omitiendo saltos de línea en la primera cadena ($guardar_venta) se ve correctamente, pero no en la segunda ($guardar_venta_producto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización:** Revisando otras preguntas/respuestas, me di cuenta que probablemente no es el salto de línea lo que hace que falle el formato, sino combinar comillas dobles y simples en una misma cadena.

Comment: ¿Cual es el `bug`? El texto se muestra como se especifica en ambos casos.

Comment: @CandidMoe, ¿por qué el `foreach()` aparece como si fuera comentario o parte de una cadena?

Comment: Buena observación. No lo había percibido. Acabo de probar la sintaxis *heredoc* para las cadenas en php, para saber si en ellas se presenta el mismo problema. **No ocurre**. Lo voy a agregar como respuesta porque se podría usar  como alternativa para respuestas php. Creo que vale la pena probar en otros lenguajes que soporten sintaxis multilínea.

Comment: @quevedo, lamentablemente hay muchos usuarios que desconocen el uso de _heredoc_ y muchos otros que no les gusta. No sé si en Javascript pase, porque la mayoría de las veces se usa en fragmento de código, pero voy a buscar.

Answer (score 2):

Está todo explicado en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/193460)

> Nota: si bien el motor de coloreado [cambió hace poco](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401031) para toda la red y eso puede afectar a algún pequeño detalle de cómo se renderiza, no afecta al comportamiento de cómo determina qué lenguaje usar para colorear, ni a la sintaxis de preguntas y respuestas, ni a las opciones disponibles para forzar un lenguaje.

En resumen:

- Tu código se veía mal coloreado porque estabas en una pregunta cuya etiqueta principal era SQL y estabas publicando código de PHP. -Así es, si el motor asume que es SQL, claro que le va a errar en los colores de otro lenguaje! jaja.
- Se veía "mejor" en una sola línea porque esa es la sintaxis de SQL.
- Las comillas simples y dobles se interpretan *exactamente* de la forma que tiene que interpretarse para SQL.
- Acá en Meta, también hay coloreado. El tema es que por omisión, se asume que no hay, pero se puede forzar al igual que en cualquier otra pregunta o respuesta.
- En cualquier publicación acá en Meta o en el principal se puede forzar que se interprete el código con el lenguaje que quieras, usando esta sintaxis antes del código (ejemplo para PHP):

  ```
  <!-- language: lang-php -->

      //tu código
      $var = "select * from blablabla";
  ```

---

**Para demostrar el punto**

Así se ve tu código usando `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`:

```sql
//Comentario 1
$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa (numero, cliente, fecha, forma_pago)
                         VALUES ('$numero', '$cliente', '$fecha', '$forma_pago')";

//Comentario 2
foreach ($producto as $index => $prd) {
    //etc.
}
```

Y así se ve tu código usando `<!-- language: lang-php -->`:

```php
//Comentario 1
$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa (numero, cliente, fecha, forma_pago)
                         VALUES ('$numero', '$cliente', '$fecha', '$forma_pago')";

//Comentario 2
foreach ($producto as $index => $prd) {
    //etc.
}
```

Una muy buena: a partir del [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/19911?noredirect=1) de [Triby](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) me puse a leer un poco la página de [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/), y encontré que `<!-- language: lang-php-template -->` va muy bien con código de PHP cuando está dentro de las etiquetas de un html.

```php-template
<?php
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
?>
<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción
      </th>
      <th class="fecha">Fecha aprox
      </th>
      <th>Comentarios
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="scroll">
          <?php echo $row["DESCRIPCION"] ?>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["FECHA"])) ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button style="width:15px;" class="openModal"
                id="<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>">
          <img src="images/modificar.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;">
        </button>
        <div class="scroll" id='comentario<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>"'>
          <?php echo $row["COMENTARIOS"]?>   
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
  </tbody>               
</table>
```

Igualmente, para estos casos mixtos, creo que conviene dejar el lenguaje en `default`, que colorea bien.

Comment: Aún especificando la etiqueta con `<!-- language: lang-php -->` o 3 acentos graves seguidos de `lang-php` sigue habiendo errores, como en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395168/intento-que-mi-tabla-se-actualice-con-ajax)

Comment: @Triby me imagino que se debe a que no es código puro de PHP sino HTML con las etiquetas de PHP... Probá con `lang-php-template`

Comment: (Aclaro igual que no soy desarrollador de highlight.js, ni de SO.. podés encontrar algún error y no tenemos otra opción más que levantar un ticket/publicar en MSE/llorar... Simplemente describí cómo está funcionando para identificar un lenguaje)

Comment: @Triby recién ahora se me ocurre que no es tanto lo que estás intentando reportarlo como [bug], sino más bien que se vea bien el código en las preguntas de PHP... Lee la última línea de https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info, ahí está definido como `lang-php`... Lo que deberíamos es pedir que un moderador lo cambie a `default`, y así se van a colorear bien (o al menos mucho mejor).

Answer (score 1):

Esto no es una respuesta calificada. Pero, la observación de @Triby me indujo a preguntarme si el problema también se presenta cuando se usa sintaxis *heredoc* para asignar el contenido de variables en [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) y decidí hacer una prueba.
La transcribo para que se pueda observar el resultado:

```
<?php
// cadena heredoc
$cad1 = <<<CAD
aquí va un grupo con entrecomillado mixto "exterior 'interior
a medias $variable' fin exterior"
CAD;
$usocad = hagoAlgo($cad);
```

Cuando probé el código que incluyo arriba mientras escribía una respuesta que descarté el resaltado era correcto. No se percibía en él, el error anotado en la pregunta.
[image: imagen de la prueba]

Si lo prueban notarán que $variable es marcado como una variable *viva* dentro del bloque de código. **No entiendo por qué razón el resaltado no se percibe en meta.**

Comment: _No entiendo por qué razón el resaltado no se percibe en meta._ Imagino que es porque _meta_ no está orientado a programación, sino a discusiones.

Comment: @Triby Lo pensé. Pero **descarté la posibilidad** porque creí que los objetos de edición usan **una misma clase base** por la uniformidad del diseño y porque ambos soportan markdown.

Comment: @triby. Lo lóǵico sería consistencia en la UI, pero la UI no es consistente tampoco dentro de SOes. Por ejemplo, CTRL-K no funciona dentro de los comentarios, pero `si usando marcas`. Tampoco se puede usar Return.

Answer (score 1):

### Actualización:

Hace algunos días noté que en *METAen* se anunció el [cambio de herramienta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1), por lo que ahora nos corresponde adaptarnos a las novedades.

No sé que tan conveniente sea crear una pregunta aquí con las diferencias y cómo solventar problemas de formato.

**Fin de actualización.**

El mayor problema es que el coloreado de código no es herramienta propia de **Stack Exchange** y cualquier error debe reportarse en [github del desarrollador](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues) y vaya que hay algunos elementos pendientes de solución.

Leyendo [*METAen*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), se ve que hay mucho camino por recorrer para tener un buen decorador de código.

En teoría, el sistema tratará de identificar el lenguaje con base en las etiquetas usadas, sin embargo, no hay garantía de que funcione. Una de las opciones mencionadas en *METAen* es especificar el lenguaje, por ejemplo:

````
```lang-php
// Aquí el código
```
````

También podría especificarse solo la etiqueta, sin el prefijo *lang-*

````
```php
// Aquí el código
```
````

Comment: Esta aclaración **el coloreado de código no es herramienta propia** es bien importante. Estás indicando el "germen del mal" quiere decir que el coloreado puede ser inesperado en muchos aspectos. De modo que se hace necesario observar el efecto para asegurar que no vuelva confusas las respuestas.