# ¿Hay un error en los colores de sintaxis de código en el caso de PHP?

Tags: soporte, resaltado-de-sintaxis

Observen esta imagen de un código en esta pregunta: [mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/399074/29967) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las partes en los recuadros son código, pero aparecen en verde, como si fuesen comentarios.

Si observan el código de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/399092/29967) ocurre lo mismo, todo lo que hay a partir de esta línea aparece en verde:

```
if ( $datos=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") ) {
```

¿Por qué ocurre eso? Es incómodo para leer/analizar el código en las preguntas y respuestas. ¿Cómo se puede corregir ese problema?

Comment: Revise la pregunta y sólo las cadenas aparecen en verde. En la respuesta parece confundirse cuando una cadena contiene a otra ("SELECT ... '$id' ")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es un error. La etiqueta principal de esa pregunta es [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). Y si observás al final de https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info

> Lenguaje de código (utilizado para [resaltar la sintaxis](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js)): lang-sql

Por lo tanto, esa etiqueta que es la principal está definiendo el color de resaltado por omisión de preguntas y respuestas de esa publicación. Referencia: [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/193460) (desactualizada desde el cambio a [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md), pero válida en todo el resto).

Si le pedimos que resalte código de PHP con la sintaxis de SQL, claramente van a pasar cosas como las que estás mostrando.

Para solucionarlo, se puede explicitar el lenguaje de resaltado `default`:

````
``` default
código acá
```
````

o también se podría usar `lang-php-template`.

en este caso lo que **no** se debería usar es `lang-php`, porque aunque resuelve la mayoría de los problemas, asume código puro de PHP (es decir, sin estar dentro del tag `<?php ?>`, y por ende puede errarle cuando haya etiquetas HTML en un código mixto). Para mí es un error que la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) esté definida en el sitio como `lang-php`, y creo que debería ser `default`, porque `default` colorea bien tanto HTML como PHP. Si tuviese `default`, al agregar la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) se resolvería el resaltado de (creo que) todas las preguntas de PHP.

Para ambas publicaciones que mencionás, si ves la edición que tuvo la pregunta (luego de que publicaras), en la que se agregó la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), te das cuenta de que soluciona (creo que) todos los problemas que tenían.

**Ejemplo**:

- con `lang-sql`

  ```sql
  <?php
      $q = "select * from tabla where x = 'abc'";
      //comentario
      $a = "se ve mal";
  ?><div style="color:black;">
  ```
- con `lang-php-template`

  ```php-template
  <?php
      $q = "select * from tabla where x = 'abc'";
      //comentario
      $a = "se ve <b>bien</b>";
  ?><div style="color:black;" />
  ```

Comment: También hay una propuesta en https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354793 que me encantaría que se implemente, porque creo que soluciona muchos de estos problemas

Comment: Muchas gracias, desconocía todo lo que refieres en esta excelente respuesta.

Comment: ¿Por qué el resaltado de esa publicación es el de mysql si php es la etiqueta principal?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' porque originalmente sólo tenía [tag:mysql], luego publicó acá y más tarde [le editaron la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/399074/revisions) agregando [tag:php] solucionando todo el resaltado

Comment: Caramba. O sea que cambiar las etiquetas de una pregunta implica que el resaltado de las respuetas cambia. ¿Y qué pasaría, me pregunto, si de repente la etiqueta mysql tuviera más preguntas que la de php? En tal caso, en tooodas las preguntas se cambiaría el resaltado. Habría pensado que se implementaba de forma que siempre aplicaba el resaltado vigente cuando se publica la respuesta y que para hacerle un "rebake" había que editarla.

Comment: ...aunque pensándolo bien, quizás mientras no se edite la pregunta, se sigue manteniendo la etiqueta que originalmente estaba como principal (esta parte realmente no la sé). Sí estoy seguro que una edición en la pregunta traería el problema (verificado en el caso de la pregunta de A.Cedano)

Comment: Tiene matiz el tema: _Stack Exchange usa las etiquetas de la pregunta para inferir el lenguaje que estás usando. Si hay más de una etiqueta que tiene resaltador de sintaxis, usa uno por defecto y deja que Prettify infiera cuál es el mejor lenguaje a usar._, de [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83). De todos modos, añadir una etiqueta "potente" (como php en este caso) claramente condiciona.