# ¿Cuáles son todos los lenguajes disponibles para resaltado en el sitio?

Tags: discusión, resaltado-de-sintaxis

Se usa highlight.js para el [resaltado de sintaxis](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/193460).
Si quiero forzar un lenguaje en el código de una publicación, se hace con

````
``` lang-<lenguaje>

//código

```
````

Sin embargo, la versión que usa el sitio puede no ser la última, y los lenguajes habilitados pueden no ser todos.

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener la lista **actual** de todos los lenguajes disponibles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

El script que usan todos los sitios de la red está en https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js.
De ahí se puede examinar el código buscando las líneas con `hljs.registerLanguage()`.

Este snippet te muestra todos los lenguajes que se usan actualmente:

```js
const reLang = /^[ \t]*hljs\.registerLanguage\( *'([-\w]+)'\s*,/mg;
let lang, res = [], n = 1;
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(content=>{
      while (lang = reLang.exec(content)) {
          res.push((''+n++).padStart(2,'0') + '. lang-' + lang[1]);
      }
      document.body.innerText = res.join('\n');
  })
```